# Can $x^y$ be represented as a product of two univariate functions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Very simple question. I have the function $x^y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and I want to represent it as a product of two univariate functions of $x$ and $y$, or, in other words, I want to find some closed expressions for $f,g$ in the relation
$$
x^y = f(x)g(y).
$$
I have looked into this problem for a little while now, and while I have no justification for it, I have the suspicion that there are no univariate $f, g$ that satisfy this equation. However, I also believe that this problem might have a solution using differential equations, which I have yet to really study, so it's possible that the problem is just out of my grasp for now.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose such a decomposition were possible.  We remark that $1^y=1$ for all $y$.  Thus we'd have $f(1)g(y)=1$ for all $y$, hence $g$ would be a constant, a clear contradiction.

Comment: Clear and concise. I don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks!